# How to use the Ruby stdlib profiler with Jruby?

Tags: ruby, profiling, jruby, ruby-std

I am trying to use Ruby's standard lib profiler, and I am not using ruby-prof because this is a jruby project.

Though, I am allways getting something like:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
  0.00     0.93      0.00        1     0.00   930.00  #toplevel
```

The code that generates this is:

```
require 'profiler'
Profiler__.start_profile
#  profiling_result = RubyProf.profile do
result=  handle_request

#  end
#Profiler__.stop_profile

#  printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/profiler/#{Time.now.to_i}.flat","w") do |f|
  Profiler__.print_profile f
end
Profiler__.stop_profile
```

Comment: Cue comment suggesting stack sampling instead in 5, 4, 3 ...

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand what are you trying to convey through your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the JRuby built-in profiler, detailed here: http://danlucraft.com/blog/2011/03/built-in-profiler-in-jruby-1.6/

The stdlib profiler uses feature of Ruby that incur a tremendous perf hit (set_trace_func, among others). You'll get better results using the built-in profiler, which avoids such overhead.